# Setting image in android twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter

I have an app where I integrate android & twitter. The application permission is given but while loading the profile and fetching the data from the profile, my app stops responding. `Logcat` shows the `NullPointerException` at **onPostExecution**. So, I have put the image loading part of the code under comments. Can anyone make the change in the comments so that the app works with image loading alongside it?
here is my code for Profile `Fragment`:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
TextView prof_name;
SharedPreferences pref;
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView prof_img,tweet,signout,post_tweet;
EditText tweet_text;
ProgressDialog progress;
Dialog tDialog;
String tweetText;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
    prof_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prof_name);
    pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    prof_img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.prof_image);
    tweet = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tweet);
    signout = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.signout);
    signout.setOnClickListener(new SignOut());
    tweet.setOnClickListener(new Tweet());
    new LoadProfile().execute();
    return view;
}
private class SignOut implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN", "");
        edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", "");
        edit.commit();  
        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();               
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, login);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();


    }

}
private class Tweet implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        tDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        tDialog.setContentView(R.layout.tweet_dialog);
        tweet_text = (EditText)tDialog.findViewById(R.id.tweet_text);
        post_tweet = (ImageView)tDialog.findViewById(R.id.post_tweet);
        post_tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new PostTweet().execute();  
            }
        });

        tDialog.show();


    }}

private class PostTweet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Posting tweet ...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            tweetText = tweet_text.getText().toString();
            progress.show();

    }
       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(pref.getString("CONSUMER_KEY", ""));
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(pref.getString("CONSUMER_SECRET", ""));



            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(pref.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN", ""), pref.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", ""));
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            try {
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(tweetText +" @learn2crack ");
                return response.toString();
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


       return null;
       }
       protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
           if(res != null){
           progress.dismiss();
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tweet Sucessfully Posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           tDialog.dismiss();
           }else{
               progress.dismiss();
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error while tweeting !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               tDialog.dismiss();
           }

       }
   }
private class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Loading Profile ...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();

    }
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(pref.getString("IMAGE_URL", "")).getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return bitmap;
       }
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
          /* Bitmap image_circle = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

           BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
           Paint paint = new Paint();
           paint.setShader(shader);
           Canvas c = new Canvas(image_circle);
           c.drawCircle(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2, image.getWidth()/2, paint);
           prof_img.setImageBitmap(image_circle);*/
           prof_name.setText("Welcome " +pref.getString("NAME", ""));

           progress.hide();

       }
   }
```

}

Comment: can you please post error log ?

Comment: have you check pref value in onPostExecute ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana-The logcat is giving null pointer at onPostExecution. and yes I have checked the pref values. its just that I'm not getting the image. apart from that, everything works just works fine.

Comment: In which line the NullPointerException? prof_name.setText("Welcome " +pref.getString("NAME", ""));?

Comment: @Rami- Bitmap image_circle = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: Check the returned value of *pref.getString("IMAGE_URL", "")*, I think it return "" and cause the exception.